# Installing Julia BinaryBuilder.jl packages on Windows 7

Tags: windows, julia, package-managers

I am having difficulty installing various Julia packages on my Windows 7 laptop. When trying to `add` certain packages I receive the following error:

```
(v1.3) pkg> add MbedTLS
  Updating registry at `C:\Users\uname\.julia\registries\General`
  Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
 Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unable to automatically install 'MbedTLS' from 'C:\Users\uname\.julia\packages\MbedTLS_jll\wUtL4\Artifacts.toml'
```

Several packages install happily, and I think I've narrowed it down to those that are supplied via `BinaryBuilder.jl`, such as `MbedTLS`, `Arpack`, `OpenSpecFun`. If I try to install any packages that have any such packages as a dependency I get the same error message when it hits one of these (initially encountered when I was trying to install `Genie`.

I am using the latest Julia (1.3.1), although I encountered the same issue previously in 1.2 - I managed to fix things eventually in that case, and tried a similar approach (manually downloading and placing in packages folder) but have not been able to fix things in this instance (although I confess that my notes were a little lacking so can't be certain I'm doing the correct thing). The various packages seem to exist in `...\.julia\packages\` (although not in `.julia\compiled`), but julia complains whenever I try to `add` them to some environment.

I don't think I understand julia's package system well enough to see quite what is going on here. I have seen other people with similar issues but not found anything yet which has worked - any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: In an attempt to temporarily workaround I have been able to `add` an older version of `MbedTLS` (0.7.0), which was the last version before using `MbedTLS_jll` over `BinaryProvider`. To do this I had to run julia with administrator rights - however I then get errors when I try to `build`: `ERROR: LoadError: Could not download https://github.com/JuliaWeb/MbedTLSBuilder/releases/download/v0.17.0/MbedTLS.v2.16.0.x86_64-w64-mingw32.tar.gz to C:\Users\uname\.julia\packages\MbedTLS\a1JFn\deps\usr\downloads\MbedTLS.v2.16.0.x86_64-w64-mingw32.tar.gz:`

Comment: However if I manually download from the specified source and place it in the folder, then I can (if running as administrator) complete the build process. I did restart julia in between, which I'm not sure is necessary - but certainly some initial attempt at manually placing in folder led to the build process deleting my download and then erroring out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually is due to an issue with your powershell installation, which is what we use to download these binaries in Julia 1.3 and 1.4.  In particular, most of the internet (including GitHub, where most of our binaries are hosted) [disabled SSL v3, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 in 2018](https://github.blog/2018-02-01-crypto-removal-notice/). Windows 7 is old enough that it doesn't speak TLS 1.2+ natively; instead you must install two packages:

- This [TLS `easy_fix`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in)
- [Windows Management Framework 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/wmf/overview) or later, to get Powershell v3+

This is necessary on Windows 7, but not on Windows 10.  For more instructions, you can read the Julia platform specific instructions: https://julialang.org/downloads/platform/

Comment: Thanks very much, that's very helpful. I will try this out later

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks for sharing that page, obviously didn't check it properly enough back when I installed Julia